# How do I change the settings programmatically with C to make the width and height of characters in a Linux terminal the same without any spacing?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to implement the snake game for Linux terminal with C programming language.

Here is the code for the background which is simply a set of "walls".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("\033[H");
    printf("\033[J");
    for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++)
        printf("**");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("**");
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            printf("  ");
        printf("**");
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++)
        printf("**");
    printf("\n");
    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I got in the terminal

[image]

and this when replacing "  " with "00"

[image]

I'm not sure if it's some kind of spacing between lines of the terminal window. It's necessary for normal use, but not for a console game.

How do I change the settings programmatically with C to make the width and height of characters the same without any spacing, like the one shown below?

[image]

In other words, how do I make 20 rows by 20 columns of characters giving a square area with C?

Comment: That just might be how the `*` character is in that font. Try drawing a full-height character like `O` or `X` next to an edge for comparison.

Comment: It's cool that you are doing this yourself, but have you considered [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) or something? You might check out box-drawing characters?

Comment: If you mean with X then it is controlled by the `XTerm*scaleHeight:` setting in the `Xresources` file. Default is generally `1.00` though many distros add a bit of height, e.g. `1.05`. You can compress by subtracting from `1.0` (e.g. `.95`). If your interface is Wayand -- than I have no idea. I doubt there is a setting, but welcome being informed there is.

Comment: Click on the icon of your example program, open Properties... and change the font to something else. Keep changing until it looks like your Linux. Or make it fullscreen. Does the Snake.exe have any control over the window font or spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ncursesw, and you can use Unicode Block Elements (█ ▌ ▐ ▀ ▄ ▖▗ ▘ ▙ ▚ ▛ ▜▝ ▞ ▟ and ░ ▒ ▓) and Box Drawing characters (─ ┐┌ │└ ┘├ ┤┬ ┴ ┼ ═ ╗ ╔ ║╚ ╝╠ ╣ ╦ ╩ ╬ ╒╓ ╕╖╘╙ ╛╜╞╟╡╢╤ ╥ ╧ ╨ ╪ ╫) and other Unicode characters like Geometric Shapes (■□▣▪▫◤◣◢◥ ▤ ▥ ▦ ▧ ▨ ▩ ● ◎ ◉ ◌ ○ ◯), depending on the glyphs provided by the font you use in your terminal.

(If you want a more square glyphs, just pick a more square font, like Courier New.  Most monospaced fonts are rather rectangular, taller than they are wide, though.)

For wide character constants and wide strings, you prepend an `L` before the quotes.  For example, `L'▒'` is the wide character constant specifying medium fill, and `L"╔═╤═══╤══╗"` is a wide string containing ten wide characters.

(Wide does not mean visually wide, it is just what the C standard calls these facilities.  Normal and wide I/O cannot be mixed in the same stream.  For ncurses, ncurses is the standard non-wide terminal curses library, and ncursesw is the wide version.)

As a bonus, you get nonblocking keyboard input support, for making your own terminal games (like [rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_%28video_game%29) or [nethack](https://www.nethack.org/)).

Note that I don't use Windows, so I don't know how well WSL/WSL2 supports wide I/O yet.  In the past, native windows programs needed some additional calls for wide I/O, but ncurses 6.2 INSTALL file says it now has code to support Windows command line too.  The question is tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), and ncursesw works fine in basically all terminal types in Linux, Mac OS, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, etc.

Comment: Thank you. What about the question in my OP, that is, how to make the width and height of characters the same without any spacing? In other words, how do I make 20 rows by 20 columns of characters giving a square area with C?

Comment: @yaojp: You can't. Plain and simple. The physical dimensions of each character cell are determined bya the terminal (and the font it's using). Generally speaking these parameters can not be changed. In particular cases (a very specific terminal) there might be command control sequences that allow you to load a different font or specify character cell dimensions directly. But this depends on if the terminal being used actually offers this features, and if so, then the commands are specific to that particular terminal implementation.

Comment: @yaojp: As datenwolf said, the program cannot.  What you can do, is use a square monospace font like [Deferral](https://github.com/brianbruggeman/Deferral).  Or, instead of a terminal application, you can create a graphical application using for example [SDL](https://libsdl.org/).